# =& $foo or = &$foo, What's the difference?

Tags: php

I was studying about references and noticed that both forms can make a variable a reference. What's the difference between them, and if they are the same, which one is better to use?

```
  $var = 69   $var2 =& $var 
  
  //or   

  $var = 69   $var2 = &$var
```

Comment: `$var2 =& $var` creates a direct reference, meaning any changes to one variable will definitely affect the other one. `$var2 = &$var`  creates a reference at "assignment time", but they are not directly linked therefore subsequent changes to `$var` will not affect `$var2`.

Comment: As per use... it depends on what you want and need

Comment: There's not any prove provided for the statements of I_throw_but_dont_catch. For now I assume these two variants executes exactly the same. Whitespace is often ignored.

Comment: [They're the same](https://3v4l.org/YBu50). The only difference is personal preference of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases of $var2=& $var and $var2 = &$var, $var2 is a reference to $var1. Thus changing the variable $var will affect $var2. Though the latter one has the right syntax the PHP forgives and accepts the space in the former one. But in some other programming languages, they are not the same. For example, in C/C++ the former represents a memory location